# Explanation of closed posts

Tags: support

I have question I asked on *[server fault <-mistake on my part, long day]* **StackOverflow**, it was originally locked by mods asking for debugging details. I *thought* I had explained the issue fairly well. So I edited the post to add the code I had tried, examples of what did not work, and what did. I replied to comments for clarification, been one that seemed to be traveling in the correct direction. Question  was on UI automation, nothing sketchy or malicious about it.

Question was abruptly deleted. I mean that's cool and all, but with no PM system, I have no idea why. And no idea how to find out why. There were reference links to "debugging information" that seems to me that I satisfied.

Not really challenging it being deleted, I can only assume there *were* reasons, but if users have no way to get clarification or explanation, how do we expect that they will not keep repeating the mistake? OR just go to other sites because it makes no sense to them? Is the whole community just "RTFM, and if anything does not make sense, tough luck buddy?"

Comment: Are you looking for general information on how to get info about a specific post or asking for the reasons for moderation of a specific question? If you're looking for info about a specific question, then you should include the [meta-tag:specific-question] tag and a link to the question, or people won't really be able to help you. You can see a list of your deleted questions [here](https://serverfault.com/users/deleted-questions/current). A link to the page of your deleted questions is at the bottom of [your list of questions](//serverfault.com/users/106116/sabre?tab=questions)

Comment: The post to me reads it is "deleted & hidden", so I did not know that *could* be done, but here it is if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345169/text-of-desktop-icons-on-windows It read "Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers." which I went back and added two methods tried and a functional one for comparison, the reward for that was deletion without explanation. Did not read forbidden, or off topic, or anything other than "give more info", I did, and it as nuked. Someone was even trying to help... And downvotes for asking why?..

Comment: Really all I want is a chance to understand why, and the ability to fix it.  As stated been here over a decade, been helped a lot, and heled a lot of people, and this makes zero sense, perhaps an explanation would lift that feeling?

Comment: Iam on my mobile, so the post history is harder to see, but from what I seen it was the roomba bot from stackexchange that removed the post, as it was kinda old, unanswered and with a negative score.

Comment: I posted it last night?

Comment: @yagmoth555 no it was deleted by three ordinary users, two hours after being asked. Need 10k on SO to see it, Roomba deletes only after a while, not couple of hours.

Comment: @Sabre it's a known problem on Stack Overflow. Many high rep users are very "trigger happy" and delete closed questions quickly, never giving chance for editing. But please take this to Meta Stack Overflow, and expect lots of downvotes and negative comments if you choose to do that. :/

Comment: As pointed out below, I post on many sites, yet is was stackverflow, not server fault, apologies for the confusions. Editing original post...

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard why is that not moderated at a higher level? Bad management can tank companies, and forums. People are already scared AI is going to replace the human element of most internet Q&A, humans with the ego of children with power will make that a complete certainty. We have a banner that say "someone is new, please be nice", maybe one that reads "this person has been here a while, don't  be an ***?" And the downvotes for asking for clarity is just asinine patronage to the egos to get a ticket into the circle?... Makes no sense for a "help forum". Arrogant != Erudite ;-)

Comment: @Sabre long story short, that's one of the most sensitive pain point, where many very active and veteran users are on one side, trying to keep Stack Overflow high quality, and on the other side the management, who does try to help the new users in various ways. It's all out of my paygrade and I'm on the fence about it, if you have time, jump into Meta Stack Overflow and follow the rabbit hole.

Comment: \**[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/)*. \**[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour)*

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might be confused about which site you're asking about.

You say:

> ... question I asked on server fault, ...

But your link in a comment is to a question on Stack Overflow, not Server Fault.  Based on that, and your mention of adding code to your question, I think you must be asking about a question you posted on SO, not SF.

Also, as another SF mod pointed out, your most recent closed/deleted question on SF is from Sep 2022, not "last night."